# Unable to vertically align horizontal JSeparator in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, border-layout, jseparator

Using BorderLayout I have put two different JButtons, one on the left (west) and one on the right (east), and a horizontal JSeparator in the center. What I want to do is to y-align the separator to the center, instead of to the top as it is now. I have already tried to use the following method on the separator

```
setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

but it has absolutely no effect. What am I missing? If it is not possible, is there any other way to do that without using external libraries?

This is what I get:

[image: Image of the problem]

and this is what I want to achieve:

[image: Image of the solution]

This is the sample code that I am using (JPanels on top and bottom were added just for clarity):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SeparatorTest extends JFrame{

    JButton btn1 = new JButton("button1");
    JSeparator sep = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("button2");

    public SeparatorTest() {
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JPanel());
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, btn1);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, sep);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, btn2);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new JPanel());

        setSize(300, 85);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SeparatorTest().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1: I don't mind the layout as long as it looks the same, I used BorderLayout here due to its simpleness.**

Comment: Does it "HAVE" to be done with a `BorderLayout`?

Comment: No, as long as it looks the same. I though about using `GridBagLayout` at first, but for such a simple layout I have chose `BorderLayout` to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will have to do with how the `JSeparator` UI delegate decides how to paint the component, which, based on your tests, seems to want to always paint the separator starting at a `y` position of `0`.

Instead, you might need to wrap the `JSeparator` in another panel which can use a different layout manager which meets your needs, like `GridBagLayout` for example (of course you could just use `GridBagLayout` to start with, but I'm aiming for the smallest change possible ;))

[image: buttons]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SeparatorTest extends JFrame {

    JButton btn1 = new JButton("button1");
    JSeparator sep = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("button2");

    public SeparatorTest() {

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        pane.add(sep, gbc);

        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JPanel());
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, btn1);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, pane);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, btn2);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new JPanel());

        setSize(300, 85);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                SeparatorTest frame = new SeparatorTest();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```